# creating a monorepo without hosting on a package registry and installing via bitbucket

Tags: javascript, git, npm, lerna, monorepo

At my organization, we are trying to create a monorepo of react components so they can be used on several sites.

We currently have a repo called react-components hosted on bitbucket and we wanted to set it up as a monorepo using lerna.js so the structure would look like

```
packages
    package_1
         package.json
         dist
    package_2
         package.json
         dist
```

However we don't host our npm packages on a registry but rather bitbucket and install them from there

so I'd like to be able to install each package into our websites via package.json like

```
"@company_name/react_components/package_1": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.ds.company_name.com:7999/np/react-components.git#personal/jdaly/testBranch",
```

however I don't think you can have that path in a package.json
so it should be more like

```
"@company_name/react_components": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.ds.company_name.com:7999/np/react-components.git#personal/jdaly/testBranch",
```

and import like

```
import package_1 from "@company_name/react_components"
```

**is it possible to set up a monorepo without using a package registry and just import all the monerepo packages via a git link?  Haven't found much information on the web**

**I followed this tutorial https://blog.npmjs.org/post/186494959890/monorepos-and-npm
But you're still importing your modules/packages via a package registry rather thank installing via a git link**

After I build my packages I push them to the repo
and in my website package.json I am referencing it like so

```
"@company_name/react-components": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.ds.comapany_name.com:7999/np/react-components.git#personal/jdaly/firstCommit",
```

and when I go to node_modules the structure is

```
node_modules
     @company_name
          react_components
               packages
                    package_1
                    package_2
                    package_3
               lerna.json
               package.json
```

when it should be

```
node_modules
     @company_name
          react_components
                    package_1
                    package_2
                    package_3
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: perhaps you can improve your original question, I am not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The main question is in bold now
is it possible to set up a monorepo without using a package registry and just import packages via a git link? Haven't found much information on the web

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To anyone who stumbles upon this question - the answer is simple.  In order to use lerna and create a monorepo system you need to have a package registry.  That could be NPM or another product like https://verdaccio.org/ which is essentially a package registry you can use locally

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```sh
npm install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/{user}/{repository}.git
```

Sources:

- [npm-install-modules-from-bitbucket-private-repositories](https://sqllyw.wordpress.com/2015/10/17/npm-install-modules-from-bitbucket-private-repositories/)
- [git-urls-as-dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies)
- [How-can-I-install-an-npm-package-from-my-bitbucket-repository](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-can-I-install-an-npm-package-from-my-bitbucket-repository/qaq-p/752908)

Comment: we already have existing private repos in which we install packages - but we don't have anything like a monorepo set up which is different than installing individual node packages

Answer (score 0):

For some, this will suffice:

You may install packages from the same monorepo, without installing from a registry, by referencing the folder in the same repo or a tarball built in a separate folder in the same repo.

Examples:

- `npm install ../package_1`
- `npm install ../package_1.tgz`

Reference: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

See `npm install <folder>` and `npm install <tarball file>`

However, *consider carefully* before going this route for production codebases intended to be long lived. This is excellent for quick and dirty solution w/o using registry, but consider...

- How you will support multiple versions as packages produce backward-incompatible changes (major version bumps)
- How will your packages be built through your build CI/CD pipeline